# How to connect to Azure B2c via IdentityServer

Tags: identityserver4, azure-ad-b2c, capacitor

Currently I have capacitor App connecting to Azure B2C directly. However I need to connect to B2C via IdentityServer4. This is because I wanted to inject some custom claims plus to make all authentication in a centralize (IdentityServer) place.

Is it possible? If so How?

Can someone give me some directions please.

In my App, I use this capacitor plugin for authentication (https://github.com/moberwasserlechner/capacitor-oauth2)

Answer (score 2):

As @Mehrdad states, you need to add an external provider = B2C.

So something like:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("b2c", "Azure AD B2C", options =>
```

But B2C expects the client to be using the [msal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-b2c-overview) library so you will have to add extra parameters to the call e.g. the policy (?p=).

Answer (score 1):

You can find a complete guide in [Sign-in with External Identity Providers](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signin_external_providers.html)